# Syntax of SQL Server PIVOT with all COLS same except one

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

There must be a good answer for this already, but I don't see it.

I have this:

```
Field1, field2, field3, memoline
--------------------------------
1       1       1       ABC
1       1       1       DEF
2       2       2       UVW
2       2       2       XYZ
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
Field1, field2, field3, memoline1, memoline2
--------------------------------------------
1       1       1       ABC        DEF
2       2       2       UVW        XYZ
```

Fields 1, 2 & 3 are the same for each unique memoline row.

I suspect that a `PIVOT` can do this, but I've been unsuccessful because memoline is free form text and can be anything.  I do not know what it is and the `PIVOT` syntax seems to want me to know the values inside "memoline" in order to do it's thing.

Comment: Are there only two memolines for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with `PIVOT` You'll need to add a `ROW_NUMBER()` that can be used to differentiate the memoline records, if the number of memolines is unknown you could make it dynamic, but you can just add a bunch to the `IN` list as shown here:

```
;WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 'Memoline'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1, Field2, Field3 ORDER BY MEMOLINE)AS VARCHAR(3)) As NewMemo
               FROM TABLE1
              )    
SELECT *
FROM cte
PIVOT (MAX(MemoLine) FOR NewMemo IN (Memoline1,Memoline2,Memoline3,Memoline4))Pvt
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ef1c/4/0)

Answer (score 0):

If you know each row will have only two memolines then the following query will do the trick:

```
SELECT 
   FIELD1, 
   FIELD2, 
   FIELD3, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN [ORDER] = 1 THEN MEMOLINE ELSE NULL END) MEMOLINE1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN [ORDER] = 2 THEN MEMOLINE ELSE NULL END) MEMOLINE2
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 ORDER BY MEMOLINE) [ORDER]
   FROM TABLE1
) A
GROUP BY 
   FIELD1, 
   FIELD2, 
   FIELD3
```

This is the output

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Field1 field2 field3 memoline1 memoline2 ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1       1       1       ABC        DEF   ║
║ 2       2       2       UVW        XYZ   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

There is no problem if a tuple of fileds have more than 2 memolines, but this query will consider only the two first ones (ordered by text in memoline).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ef1c/1/0)